# ASP.NET Get Original Text of Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Is there any way to get the original text from a Asp:Label on a page, after the text has been altered?

with the orginal text i mean the text that is hard coded into the asp.net markup.

Comment: How has the text been altered, given that it is a label? Using JS ?

Comment: No with asp.net
textLabel.Text = "abc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way to get it back after some chages, but you could do that in some your ways, for example add custom attributes to label

```
textLabel.Attributes.Add("data", textLabel.Text);
```

and then use it on your page.
Or cache label value using js code on page startup or statically.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property that wraps the text assignment. Before the assignment take the current value and assign it to a hidden input or stick it in the session or viewstate.

Create a property that retrieves the previous value from the hidden input or session or viewstate.

Could get fancy and extend the label to add a PreviousValue property. Not sure how this would work in practice though.